# How to add concurrency to php app in heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, unicorn

i'm developing a simple php app for SEO data retrieval, using this library: 
https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats

You can check the web app here:

http://analise.rockcontent.com

I'm deploying it to heroku, looking to run multiple php processes in a single dyno. Is there anything similar to unicorn for php in heroku[1]?

[1] https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn